# Presentar los meses del año en HTML con PHP dependiendo del año actual que no sea mayor al mes actual

Tags: date

Tengo en mi proyecto un archivo que se llama "consultar_compras_mes.php" tiene el siguiente código:

```html
<?php

   require_once("../config/conexion.php");

    if(isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
        

?>


<!-- INICIO DEL HEADER - LIBRERIAS -->
<?php require_once("header.php");?>

<!-- FIN DEL HEADER - LIBRERIAS -->


  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    
   
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
       Consulta de Compras por mes
       
      </h1>
      
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
    
   <div id="resultados_ajax"></div>

     <div class="panel panel-default">
        
        <div class="panel-body">

            <form class="form-inline">
              <div class="form-group">
               
                 <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="mes" id="mes" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">MES</option>
                                <option value="01">ENERO</option>
                                <option value="02">FEBRERO</option>
                                <option value="03">MARZO</option>
                                <option value="04">ABRIL</option>
                                <option value="05">MAYO</option>
                                <option value="06">JUNIO</option>
                                <option value="07">JULIO</option>
                                <option value="08">AGOSTO</option>
                                <option value="09">SEPTIEMBRE</option>
                                <option value="10">OCTUBRE</option>
                                <option value="11">NOVIEMBRE</option>
                                <option value="12">DICIEMBRE</option>
                              </select>
                 </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <select name="ano" id="ano" class="form-control">
                                  <option value="">AÑO</option>
                                 
                                  <?php

                                      $ano = date("Y");
                                      for ($i=2008;$i<=$ano;$i++){

                                           echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                                           
                                      }

                                  ?>

                                 <!-- <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                  <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                  <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                  <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                  <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                  <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                  <option value="2020">2020</option>
                                  <option value="2021">2021</option>
                                  <option value="2022">2022</option>
                                  <option value="2023">2023</option>
                                  <option value="2024">2024</option>
                                  <option value="2025">2025</option>
                                  <option value="2026">2026</option>
                                  <option value="2027">2027</option>
                                  <option value="2028">2028</option>
                                  <option value="2029">2029</option>
                                  <option value="2030">2030</option>
                                  <option value="2031">2031</option>
                                  <option value="2032">2032</option>
                                  <option value="2033">2033</option>
                                  <option value="2034">2034</option>
                                  <option value="2035">2035</option> -->
                                </select>
                </div>
              </div>

             

               <div class="btn-group text-center">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_compra_fecha_mes"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Consultar</button>
               </div>
           </form>

       </div>
      </div>


       <!--VISTA MODAL PARA VER DETALLE COMPRA EN VISTA MODAL-->
     <?php require_once("modal/detalle_compra_modal.php");?>
    
   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">Lista de Compras por mes</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
             <table id="compras_fecha_mes_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr style="background-color:#A9D0F5">
                  <th>Ver Detalle</th>
                  <th>Fecha Compra</th>
                  <th>Número Compra</th>
                  <th>Proveedor</th>
                  <th>Cédula Proveedor</th>
                  <th>Comprador</th>
                  <th>Tipo Pago</th>
                  <th>Total</th>
                  <th>Estado</th>
                  
                 
                </tr>
                </thead>

              
                
              </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->


   <?php require_once("footer.php");?>

    <!--AJAX PROVEEDORES-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/compras.js"></script>


<?php
   
  } else {

        header("Location:".Conectar::ruta()."index.php");
        exit();
     }

?>
```

¿Como hacer para que en el select del mes con el id=mes y name=mes muestre solo los meses si esta en el año actual hasta el mes en donde esta actualmente?

Answer (score 0):

Esto se puede hacer de varias formas:

## Opción 1

1. Construir un array con los 12 nombres de los meses
2. Crear un objeto fecha con la fecha actual y extraer el mes.
3. Sacar del rango de meses que lleguen hasta la fecha actual mediante `array_slice`
4. Crear un `select` dinámico con el rango de meses

   a. Dado que los índices del array empiezan por `0` hay que aumentar en `1` dentro del bucle para que el `value` de los option adquiera `1` para Enero, `2` para Febrero, etc.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
    # 1
    $allMonths=array(
                        "ENERO",
                        "FEBRERO", 
                        "MARZO", 
                        "ABRIL", 
                        "MAYO", 
                        "JUNIO", 
                        "JULIO", 
                        "AGOSTO", 
                        "SEPTIEMBRE", 
                        "OCTUBRE", 
                        "NOVIEMBRE", 
                        "DICIEMBRE"
                    );
    # 2
    $now = new DateTime();
    $thisMonth=$now->format('n');


    # 3
    $rangeMonths = array_slice($allMonths, 0, $thisMonth); 

    # 4 
    $mSelect="<select id=\"mes\" name=\"mes\">";
    foreach ($rangeMonths as $k=>$month){
        # a
        $v=$k+1;
        $mSelect.="<option value=\"$v\">$month</option>";
    }
    $mSelect.="</select>";
    echo $mSelect;
?>
```

**Salida (según la fecha de hoy):**

```html
<select id="mes" name="mes">
  <option value="1">ENERO</option>
  <option value="2">FEBRERO</option>
</select>
```

#### Pruebas con otros valores arbitrarios:

Si la fecha fuera:

```
$now = new DateTime("2019-12-01");
```

**Salida:**

```html
<select id="mes" name="mes">
  <option value="1">ENERO</option>
  <option value="2">FEBRERO</option>
  <option value="3">MARZO</option>
  <option value="4">ABRIL</option>
  <option value="5">MAYO</option>
  <option value="6">JUNIO</option>
  <option value="7">JULIO</option>
  <option value="8">AGOSTO</option>
  <option value="9">SEPTIEMBRE</option>
  <option value="10">OCTUBRE</option>
  <option value="11">NOVIEMBRE</option>
  <option value="12">DICIEMBRE</option>
</select>
```

Si la fecha fuera:

```
$now = new DateTime("2019-05-31");
```

**Salida:**

```html
<select id="mes" name="mes">
  <option value="1">ENERO</option>
  <option value="2">FEBRERO</option>
  <option value="3">MARZO</option>
  <option value="4">ABRIL</option>
  <option value="5">MAYO</option>
</select>
```

---

## Opción 2

Esta opción se desarrolla totalmente en base a objetos de tipo temporal.

1. Para los nombres de los meses en castellano puedes usar el array de la opción 1, o una clase más avanzada o las configuraciones locales del equipo (esta última opción al menos a mi no siempre me ha funcionado).
2. Creas un objeto `DateTime` que represente el primer día del año
3. Creas otro objeto `DateTime` con la fecha actual.
4. Creas un intervalo de un mes
5. Creas un período de meses entre las dos fechas creadas en 2 y en 3. El intervalo de esa período será de un mes
6. Creamos el `select` dinámico

   a. Extraes el valor numérico del mes del objeto período

   b. Buscas el nombre del mes en el array, restando 1, por lo dicho antes, PHP indexa los arrays empezando en `0`

Este sería el código:

```
/*
    OPCIÓN 2
*/

#1 Usamos el mismo array de opción 1 para este caso

# 2 
$dateIn   = new DateTime('first day of january');

# 3
$dateOut  = new DateTime();

# 4
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');

# 5
$period   = new DatePeriod($dateIn, $interval, $dateOut);

# 6
$mSelect="<select id=\"mes\" name=\"mes\">";
foreach ($period as $mDate) {
    # a
    $nMonth=$mDate->format("n");
    # b
    $mSelect.="<option value=\"$nMonth\">{$allMonths[$nMonth-1]}</option>";
}
$mSelect.="</select>";
echo $mSelect;
```

**Salida:**

```html
<select id="mes" name="mes">
  <option value="1">ENERO</option>
  <option value="2">FEBRERO</option>
</select>
```

---

## Fiddle

Puedes ver una <kbd>[**`DEMOSTRACIÓN`**](https://rextester.com/CDAMR35390)</kbd> en línea con ambas opciones y hacer pruebas sobre el código.

Espero sea de utilidad.